# How to keep floated element from affecting "text-align: center" text?

Tags: html, css

In my code, I have a `<p>` tag, which looks like:
`<div><p>Text Here <span></span</p></div>`

I have the CSS `div { text-align:center } span { float:right }`

When I fill the span with text, it moves the text over to the left. How can I make it so that when the span is filled with text, the paragraph tag is unmoved. I cannot edit the HTML, it MUST stay exactly how it is right now

Thanks!

Comment: please post a Fiddle , btw span tag its a inline tag so doesn't need float

Comment: could you add a fiddle?

Comment: You want the span's content to overlap the paragraph's content?

Comment: Here's a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Pointy/pen/dFIhn).  The issue is that the centering of the text in the `<p>` takes into account only the available space after whatever's used up by the floated `<span>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I can think of is:

```
div {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

That takes the `<span>` completely out of the picture as far as the text outside of it is concerned. Of course, if the `<span>` gets *too* big it'll overlap the other text.